# Creating a bifurcation diagram of the logistics map

Tags: code-request

I am brand new to *Mathematica* so please keep that in mind.

I've run into trouble trying to make a bifurcation diagram. Here is what I have done:

I have a function $f(x)$ that relies on a value $r$ (The range of $r$ lies between the values $2.8<r<4$.

What I have done is that I have found 1200 equally spaced subdivisions of $r$ in this range using the code:

```
L1 := FindDivisions[{2.8, 4}, 1200]
```

Then I created 1000 points for each r value in this range using the following code:

```
x = Table[0, {1000}]
r = L1
x[[1]] = .01
For[i = 1, i < 30, i++, x[[i + 1]] = r*x[[i]] (1 - x[[i]])]
x
```

(Is this correct?)

Now what I need to do is take the last 100 points of each list (for a given `r` value) that were generated above. Then I must take those 100 values and plot them on a graph where r is on the *x*-axis and all the points corresponding to `y` are plotted above `r`.

Basically I need to join each value of `r` (there are 1200 of them) with its corresponding list of 1000 points. Then I must only take the last 100 points of this list and plot them against the specific `r` value. I must do this for all the `r` values.

Im totally lost on how to do this! Can anyone give me a few pointers?

Comment: What is your function `f`? Have you see `Part` (i.e. `[[ ]]`), `Span`, and `ListPlot`? Have you searched this site for "bifurcation"? [Quite a few results pop up](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=bifurcation) that may be helpful.

Comment: My function is f(x)=rx(1-x). I've searched quite a bit but I cant find how to join a point with only certain values of a given set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

George has already provided a solution, but **let's try and build up to it piece by piece** so we can understand what we are doing. Coming from the worlds of loops, *Mathematica*'s programming style can be confusing.

First of all, we need a way of representing the function to be recursively applied. A [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) would be great for this. For instance:

```
r # (1 - #) &
```

We will then use [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) to apply this recursively a set number of times, in your case 1000 times, to the $0.01$ starting value:

```
NestList[r # (1 - #) &, 0.01, 1000]
```

This would generate a list of 1001 elements (including the starting point); we only want the last 100 elements of this list, so we use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) (i.e. `[[...]]`) and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) (i.e. `;;`) to select those:

```
NestList[r # (1 - #) &, 0.01, 1000 - 1][[-100 ;;]]
```

We would like to keep track of the value of $r$ that generated each of those 100x values of the recursion, so we transform each element in the list into a sublist of the form `{r, generatedvalue}`, by mapping another simple pure function `{r, #} &` on the list obtained from `NestList` (see [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and its shorthand `/@`):

```
{r, #} & /@ NestList[r # (1 - #) &, 0.01, 1000][[-100 ;;]]
```

We now need to apply this recursion to each value of $r$ in your interval of interest. We can  use [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) to generate such a list:

```
Subdivide[2.8, 4, 1200]
```

This will generate a list of $1201$ values, i.e. $1200$ equally spaced subdivisions as requested. We will use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to run the recursion multiple times, each time with a different value of $r$ from that list above, and save the result in a variable called `nestedlist`:

```
nestedlist =
  Table[
    {r, #} & /@ NestList[r # (1 - #) &, 0.01, 1000][[-100 ;;]],
    {r, Subdivide[2.8, 4, 1200]}
  ];

Dimensions[nestedlist]
(*  Out: {1201, 100, 2} *)
```

The output of [`Dimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html) shows us that our `nestedlist` contains 1201 lists, one per value of $r$, each of which contains 100 pairs of values, i.e. the `{r, generatedvalue}` pairs we wanted. This is too "nested"; we really only want a long list of such pairs, so we can "flatten out" the top level of this nested list, to obtain a list of $1201\times100=120100$ pairs. We use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) (together with a level specification, 1) for that, and we save the result in `flatlist`:

```
flatlist = Flatten[nestedlist, 1];
(* Out: {120100, 2} *)
```

Now we are ready to plot these points using [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html):

```
ListPlot[flatlist]
```

[image: bifurcation]

Comment: Wow! Thanks MarcoB! This really helps me out! Thanks for writing this up!

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent You are very welcome

Answer (score 9):

```
f[r_] := NestList[ r # (1 - #) &, .01, 1000][[-100 ;;]]
ListPlot[Flatten[Table[ {r, #} & /@ f[r] , {r, 2.8, 4, 1/1000}], 1]]
```

[image]

if you want to fix your loop approach it should look something like this:

```
L1 = Subdivide[2.8, 4, 1200];
ListPlot[
 Flatten[Table[
   x = Table[0, {1000}];
   x[[1]] = .01;
   Do[x[[i + 1]] = r*x[[i]] (1 - x[[i]]), {i, 999}];
   {r, #} & /@ x[[-100 ;;]], {r, L1}], 1] ]]
```

Comment: Ahh! This is great! Thanks George -