# Change "ListPlot" to 16 bit accuracy?

Tags: code-request

I have (with [the help of this forum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113784/27951)) managed to plot a bifurcation diagram with the following code:

```
F = (r # (1 - #) &)
S = (Subdivide[3.84, 3.855, 1200])

nestedlist = Table[{r, #} & /@ NestList[F, 0.00000000001, 1000][[-100 ;;]], {r, S}];
flatlist = Flatten[nestedlist, 1];

ListPlot[flatlist, PlotRange -> {.45, .55}
```

I'm trying to change my plot to 16-bit accuracy, and I was told to use the code:

```
to16bits[#_] := Floor[2^16*#]*2.^-16
```

How exactly can I integrate this into the code above? I've tried many different things but I only manage to get "Options expected (instead of Null) beyond position 1" or "infinity" as an output. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The correct syntax to define your function is `to16bits[a_] := Floor[2^16*a] * 2.^-16`. You can then map that function on `flatlist` by replacing `to16bits /@ flatlist` inside `ListPlot`. You may want to further familiarize yourself with basic *Mathematica* syntax before wading in any deeper, especially when you get into numerical minutiae. For instance, the rounding you are imposing is minimal and hard to see on a plot.

Comment: your syntax is wrong, `#` should be some symbol, eg `to16bits[x_] := Floor[2^16*x]*2.^-16`  I cant see what that will accomplish though, i.m sure that tiny roundoff is too small to discern on a plot.  (Or do you mean to do that rounding at every iteration?)

Comment: Ah! Perfect, thanks MarcoB! It worked...although I don't really see any discernable difference..which is sort of what I expected. Thanks!